# How to split polygons at intersections in ArcGIS 9.3?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-9.3, clip

I have two polygon layers. I'd like to split the features in one based on where they intersect the other layer. I've tried using the Clip tool, but there is no option to simply split the features -- you're either left with all of the overlapping parts or non-overlapping parts. I've found several Cut Features tools in some obscure extensions in 10.1, but unfortunately I don't have access to those. Can anyone advise on how to do this in out-of-the-box 9.3.1?

**UPDATE**

I'm using an ArcInfo license. Here is a visual of what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

Comment: Would you be able to edit your question to include the license level(s) that you have access to, and pictures of what you are trying to accomplish that include the input and output attributes, please ?  I suspect you need Intersect (or Union + Select if you only have an ArcView license).

Comment: That's a job for the Union geoprocessing tool - if you try it and think not can you edit your question to describe what about its output may not meet your requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The single tool most suitable to your goal is [Identity](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=identity_(analysis)), which will cut up your A layer by your B layer and not leave any polygons based on the B layer that don't overlap A. However it requires an ArcInfo license.

The next suggestion would be [Union](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Union_(Analysis)), which will return *all* polygons cut up by overlap. This will return not only the areas of common overlap between A and B, but also any areas of A **or** B even if they don't overlap.

Then there's [Intersect](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Intersect_(Analysis)), which will again cut up by overlap, but it will only return areas that are both A **and** B. If you have some areas of A that aren't overlapped by B, they will get dropped.

Finally, the long way around would be to convert both polygon layers to lines with [Polygon to Line](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Polygon_To_Line_(Data_Management)) or [Feature to Line](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Feature_To_Line_(Data_Management)), merge the two sets of lines, then convert them back to polygons with [Feature to Polygon](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Feature_To_Polygon_(Data_Management)). These again require an ArcInfo license level, and would also likely destroy any attributes without some mangement work.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [Cut Polygons](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?id=670&pid=661&topicname=Splitting%20polygon%20features&) tool within an Edit Session allows you to split polygons by drawing a line, intersections in your case.

Comment: Thanks Maksim, but the features are much too complex for me to draw lines around them.

Answer (score 1):

Can you do 2 operations, one a clip, the other an intersect and then append the 2 result sets together?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with the [identity](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=identity_%28analysis%29) tool in one step, but identity needs an ArcInfo licence.

Without this licence, you can use the union tool to create a new feature class. Then you delete the polygons where the old FID field corresponding with the polygon to split is equal to -1 (those are the polygons that only belong to the polygon that you use to split)